# List horizontally data from array

Tags: php, arrays

[image]

This is the result I've got. But I wan to display it horizontally. Can anyone help me?
Here's my code:

```
<?php
for($j = 0; $j < count($sub); $j++){
     echo "
        <table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope='col'>" . $sub[$j] . "</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
        </table>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subjects should be `th`s in **one** `tr`:

```
echo "<table class='table'><thead><tr>";
for($j = 0; $j < count($sub); $j++){
    echo "<th scope='col'>" . $sub[$j] . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr></thead></table>";
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/huIr3).